# Unable to pass String from Asynctask to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Working with fragments for the first time.

Trying to pass String values from `onPostCreate` to fragments.

```
public class FillCust extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Map<String, String>>> {
    String z = "" ;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Map<String, String>> r) {
        super.onPostExecute(r);

        custName = String.valueOf(CustData.get(0).get("A"));
        contactPerson = String.valueOf(CustData.get(0).get("B"));
        telNo = String.valueOf(CustData.get(0).get("C"));
        assignedBranch = String.valueOf(CustData.get(0).get("D"));

    }

    @Override
    protected List<Map<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
            } else {
                String query = "select * from tblCustomer_Master where Customer_ID ='" + CustID + "'";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    datanum.put("A", rs.getString("Company_Name"));
                    datanum.put("B", rs.getString("Contact_Person"));
                    datanum.put("C", rs.getString("Tel_No"));
                    datanum.put("D", rs.getString("Assigned_Branch"));
                    CustData.add(datanum);

                }
                z = "Success";
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            z = "Error retrieving data from table";

        }
        return CustData;
    }
}
```

**My interface**

```
public String getCompanyname(String result) {
   return custName ;
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from `doInBackground` .

Comment: Yes i'm returning List  "CustData" from doInbackground! hw can i use the list to pass via interface?

Comment: Oh sorry, I somehow failed to notice it. Well, I personally like to use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to post a custom event from `onPostExecute` because it's Asynchronous and you can update the UI that needs updating when you fetch the new data.

Comment: Hw can i use the EventBus concept here?

Comment: Quite simply, create your custom event which can hold whatever data you wish, for example `List<Map<String, String>>` or **whatever** works for you, and then post the event from `onPostExecute` and listen for it in your fragment.

Comment: please clraify. what is your question exactly? state what goes wrong when you run the code

Comment: Thanks a lot Vucko.. U and EventBus made my day!

Comment: Hi Vucko.. facing a problem where in among the 3 frag tabs, once i click the 3rd tab and come back to 1st the date is reset i.e no data is displayed in 1st tab...so help me out the possible reason on this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Implement your `interface` in your `fragment`, pass through `AsyncTask constructor`, call interface method in `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

First Create interface like this

```
    public interface AsyncInterface {

            public abstract void companyName(String result);
}
```

Implement this on your fragment

and call this interface method from onPostExecute() like this.

```
fragment.companyName(result);
```